# Cannot see all of nested JSON Object Properties

Tags: json, asp.net-core, depth

I have a .NET Core Web API project and one of my api actions returns an object formatted as JSON. This object has 3 levels of depth and I expect it to look like so:

```
{
    "pickupDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "pickupLocation": {
        "address1": null,
        "address2": null,
        "address3": null,
        "cityStateCountry": {
        "city": null,
        "state": null,
        "country": null
        },
        "zip": null
    },
    "po": 12345,
    "itemNameAndDesc": "BobSled"
}
```

Instead the `cityStateCountry` object just shows up as `null`. I checked using both Postman and outputting the entire json object to the view using angular.

```
{
    "pickupDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "pickupLocation": {
        "address1": null,
        "address2": null,
        "address3": null,
        "cityStateCountry": null, //???
        "zip": null
    },
    "po": 12345,
    "itemNameAndDesc": "BobSled"
}
```

To my understanding this is a server side issue. Why does .NET Core do this and how can I fix it? The action that gets the data is shown below:

```
// GET: api/Shipments/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<dynamic>> GetShipment(long id)
        {
            var ship = await _context.Shipments
                .Where(c => !c.IsProcessed)
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    c.PO,
                    c.ItemNameAndDesc
                })
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.PO == id);

            if (ship == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var shipmentformviewmodel = new ShipmentFormViewModel()
            {
                PickupDate = new DateTime(),
                PickupLocation = new PickupLocation(),
                PO = ship.PO,
                ItemNameAndDesc = ship.ItemNameAndDesc

            };

            return shipmentformviewmodel;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So not sure if you would categorize this as a "workaround" or an actual solution but the `cityStateCountry` object was literally `null` (it had none of its members initialized) so if I go in  on the .NET side and actually initialize those variables (whether in the action or just constructor), I can actually see all levels of my json object as such:

```
{
    "pickupDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "pickupLocation": {
        "address1": null,
        "address2": null,
        "address3": null,
        "cityStateCountry": {
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "country": ""
        },
        "zip": null
    },
    "po": 12345,
    "itemNameAndDesc": "BobSled"
}
```

Depending on the requirements, empty string and `null` can mean the same thing (and for my requirement this is true).